# Mobile dialog on desktop website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a website (normal, for desktop browsers) and a mobile applicaiton.

I would like to suggest the visitors to try the mobile app. I created all the detection JS, cookies on server side to remember if he didn't want it, but I have one issue - Showing the dialog.

I wanted to use jQuery UI, but the dialog dosn't look so well on mobile devices (even after adjusting sizes).

I thought about using jQuery mobile, but I get the feeling this is a bit of an over kill (adding the entire CSS and JS for just one dialog/popup, will require adding data-role to the pages and more. not sure about this.

I also thought about adding phonegap, but that feels as an even bigger overkill, just to show the message.

The message should only contain some text, and two buttons (Link to the app, or close with ajax callback to create a session/cookie var).

So what would you suggest to display this one message?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use some [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) framework that supports [ui](/questions/tagged/ui) elements. I recommend [Zurb's Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com). You also have to get look at its [Reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/reveal.php) which offers easily call modals.

Comment: I'm looking through Foundation and it looks awesome. Just wondering, is it worth the overhead? Aren't custom-made simple CSS and JS lighter?